# Example of an infinite simple extension.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm new to Field Theory and I'm looking for an example of an infinite simple extension.

> **Theorem**: The element $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if the simple extension  $F(\alpha)/F$ is finite.

Using the above theorem, I guess that something like $\Bbb{Q}({\pi})/\Bbb{Q}$ is an example of such an extension. But the proof of  $\pi$ is transcendental is not at all trivial(and I don't think I can understand the proof with my limited knowledge).

So I have got two questions:

- Is my example correct?
- Are there any methods to construct an infinite simple extension which doesn't require more sophisticated tools?

Also, I would love to see some "trivial" examples(if they exist).

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your example is correct.  Any transcendental should work, and they should all look the same.  You can just let $\alpha$ be any transcendental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your example is correct. Another example would be $k(X)/k$ where $k(X)$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $k[X]$, and $X$ is clearly transcendental.

Comment: An element is algebraic if it is killed by a polynomial, so by definition of $k[X]$ the element $X$ cannot be algebraic.